Improving Performance with React-Hook-Form v5 Watch Method in Accordion Table Inputs
I am working on a React project where I have an array of accordions, and each accordion contains a table of inputs (You, Your Wife, Total). To calculate the total, I am using the watch method from react-hook-form. However, I am experiencing performance degradation in the components.
I cannot use getValues because it does not re-render the component when the values change.
Here are some details:
Library: react-hook-form
Version: 5
Has anyone faced similar issues or can suggest an optimized way to handle this scenario?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Adding a working example of your case could help.
